# RenderScript Allocation. Read int from Allocation

Tags: android, renderscript

In Java I have this code for creating the Allocation for the intPointer. But after the renderscript computation I can't get the value of the allocation back. There is no copyTo(int) method only byte[], short[], int[], float[], bitmap.

```
    //Create Allocation
    Allocation intPointer = Allocation.createSized(renderScript, Element.I32(renderScript), 2);

    convolution.bind_intPointer(intPointer);
    convolution.forEach_root(allocationOut);

    [...]
    //read Allocation, not working
    int[] ints = new int[]{0x01234567};
    intPointer.copyTo(ints);             //does not overwrite the ints the line above
    int i = (int)ints[0];
    Log.d("ints", String.valueOf(i));
```

renderscript:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(package com.ap.wificam)
#pragma rs_fp_imprecise

rs_allocation input;
rs_allocation mask;

int32_t *intPointer = 0;

void root(uchar4* out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

    //do some stuff

    if((sum.x + sum.y + sum.z)/3 > *intPointer)
        *intPointer = (sum.x + sum.y + sum.z)/3;    //wirte data to intPointer

    *out = convert_uchar4(sum);
}
```

Log.d("ints", String.valueOf(i)); gives me `D/ints﹕ 19088743` 
and rsDebug("rs", *intPointer); `2045  0x7fd`

How can I get my int value from the Allocation?

Comment: with this code I am able to read the int:
        int[] ints = new int[]{0x0,0x0};
        intPointer = convolution.get_intPointer();
        intPointer.copyTo(ints);

the int[] array needs to have two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your RenderScript setup seems to be correct, but I think you're having problems initializing the data in the allocation correctly.

Since you're reading the values of the allocation inside RenderScript when you compare if the `sum` average is greater than `*intPointer`, you'll want to make sure the starting value for that is what you're actually expecting. Otherwise it will have uninitialized data and the `>` comparison will fail most of the time.

I guess that's what you were trying to do with `int32_t *intPointer = 0;`, but that's not really the correct way to initialize the data of pointers in C. The easiest way to do this is to do a data copy from Java right after you create the allocation:

```
Allocation intPointer = Allocation.createSized(renderScript, Element.I32(renderScript), 2);
intPointer.copy1DRangeFrom(0, 2, new int[2]);
convolution.bind_intPointer(intPointer);
```

This will make sure all values are 0 at the start of your RS kernel (since in Java, `new int[2]` creates a 0-initialized array).

Furthermore, your code might not be entirely thread-safe. Since you will have many threads reading and writing simultaneously to that single `*intPointer` address, you might run into synchronization problems, where the final value you get out of that may or may not be the true global maximum from all your threads.

I would suggest that instead of doing this, you store *all* `(sum.x + sum.y + sum.z)/3` values in an allocation that is as big as your input data, then copy that allocation back out to Java and from there, do a simple loop over its array to find the maximum value.

Properly parallelizing a maximum algorithm from inside a RenderScript kernel is actually a bit difficult to do (you can read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734275/calculate-the-sum-of-values-in-an-array-using-renderscript/21741335#21741335) I posted some time ago for more details if you're interested), so to keep things simple, you might be better off just finding the maximum from Java instead as I suggested above.